# Autofac error: The instance registration can support SingleInstance() sharing only

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

When I try to register my class with autofac I get the following error: "The instance  registration 'GetAllDivisionsCommand' can support SingleInstance() sharing only".

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, but assume it's something to do with the class having static member variables used for caching as that's the only thing that's different about this class. I haven't had any trouble registering any other classes as either SingleInstance or InstancePerDependency.

Essentially, the class is used to retrieve a rarely changing list of divisions from the database, and caches the result. Each time the command is run, it first checks for changes on the database and then re-runs the query if changes are detected; if not, it returns the cached list.

So I am trying to register GetAllDivisionsCommand with Autofac as an IGetAllDivisionsCommand. IGetAllDivisionsCommand itself implements IInjectableCommand, which is just a marker interface, and ICachedListCommand. The concrete command class inherits from the abstract base class CachedListCommand which is where the static member variables live.

Does anyone know what would cause this error message? SingleInstance won't work for me as I can't keep reusing the same session.

Code:

```
Type commandType = typeof(IInjectedCommand);
        Type aCommandType = typeof(GetAllDivisions);

        var commands =
            from t in aCommandType.Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            where t.Namespace == aCommandType.Namespace
                  && t.IsClass
                  && !t.IsAbstract
                  && (commandType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
            let iface = t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(x => "I" + t.Name == x.Name)
            select new { Command = t, Interface = iface };

        foreach (var cmd in commands)
        {
            builder.RegisterInstance(cmd.Command).As(cmd.Interface).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post some actual code with demonstrates your problem? The most interesting is your container registration and how does you `GetAllDivisionsCommand` looks like?

Comment: @nemesv I've posted the code above, but it's a lot to wade through...the container registration is at the top.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`RegisterInstace` as the name implies is for [registering instances](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ComponentCreation) not types.

What you need is `RegisterType`:

```cs
foreach (var cmd in commands)
{
    builder.RegisterType(cmd.Command).As(cmd.Interface).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

And by the way with the [Autofac scanning](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Scanning) feature your registration code is roughly equivalent:

```cs
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(aCommandType.Assembly)
    .AssignableTo<IInjectedCommand>()
    .InNamespace(aCommandType.Namespace)
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Argh, just a stupid typo - but exactly what I needed thanks. I didn't however realise I had unnecessary code so thanks for that bonus!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I did want RegisterInstance because I actually have an instance in hand that I wanted to register.
I had
    builder.RegisterInstance(myInstance).InstancePerDependency();

The documentation for InstancePerDependency reads:

> Configure the component so that every dependent component or call to
>   Resolve() gets a new, unique instance (default.)

On closer inspection, it makes sense that registering an instance with "instance per dependency" is not possible, since it is not possible for Autofac to give back a new instance each time Resolve is called if there is in fact 1 instance registered.

So, in my case, the solution was this.

```
builder.RegisterInstance(myInstance).SingleInstance();
```

The Autofac exception could possibly have been worded more clearly to explain this problem.